# passing id via url to second page

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pass id to second page which I am selecting from another table but the below code isn't working. When I do var_dump I can see that the values are what I want but the rows for main query don't show up(The title and image aren't being displayed).

I have two queries in which the one is inside the other one. Can someone help me out? The main query works fine if I get rid of the `while loop` of the second query.

```
        $paginate = new pagination($page, "SELECT * FROM table1 where title != '' ORDER BY id desc"  , $options);
           }
           }
           catch(paginationException $e)
           {
            echo $e;
            exit();
            }
           if($paginate->success == true)
            {
            $result = $paginate->resultset->fetchAll();
            foreach($result as $row)

            {
            $dx = $row['image_one'];//image_one from main query
            //second query
            $item = $mydb->prepare("select * from table2 where imageone  = ?");
            $item->bind_param('s', $dx);
            $item->execute();
            $item_res = $item->get_result();
            while($row = $item_res->fetch_assoc()){
            $rx = $row['id'];
            var_dump($rx);
            }   //the rows below aren't being displayed   
            $path = 'images/';
            echo "<a href='second.php?title=".urlencode($row['title'])." &amp;item=".$row['id']."&amp;id=".$rx."'>"."<img src='".$path."".$row['image_one']."'/></div>"."</a>";
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reassigning $row in your while loop once it exits $row is null.

Try this instead:

```
while($item_row = $item_res->fetch_assoc()) {
   $rx = $item_row['id'];
}
```

Also, instead of nested queries you should try using a join.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo "<a href='second.php?title="'.urlencode($row['title']).'" &amp;item="'.$row['id'].'"&amp;id="'.$rx.'"'>"."<img src='"'.$path.'"".$row['image_one']."'/></div>"."</a>";
```

use `' '` around var name